# SQL Server: GROUP BY Aggregation semantics with the PIVOT operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am on SQL Server 2008 and I have a table containing WA metrics of the following form :

```
CREATE TABLE #VistitorStat
(
    datelow datetime,
    datehigh datetime,
    name varchar(255),
    cnt  int
)
```

Two days worth of data in the table looks like so:

```
2009-07-25 00:00:00.000 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000   New Visitor       221
2009-07-25 00:00:00.000 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000   Unique Visitors   225
2009-07-25 00:00:00.000 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000   Return Visitors   0
2009-07-25 00:00:00.000 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000   Repeat Visitors   22
2009-07-26 00:00:00.000 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000   New Visitor       263
2009-07-26 00:00:00.000 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000   Unique Visitors   269
2009-07-26 00:00:00.000 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000   Return Visitors   4
2009-07-26 00:00:00.000 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000   Repeat Visitors   38
```

I want to group by the days and pivot the metrics into row form. The examples for using the `PIVOT` operator that I can find only show aggregation based on the `SUM` and `MAX` aggregate function. Presumably I need to convey `GROUP BY` semantics to the `PIVOT` operator -- note: I can't find any clear examples/ documentation on how to achieve this. Could someone please post the correct syntax of this -- **with the use of the PIVOT operator** -- of this  query.

If this is not possible with pivot -- can you come up with an elegant way of writing the query ? If not I'll just have to generate the data in transposed form.

Post answer edit:

I have come to the conclusion that the pivot operator is unelegant (so far so that I consider it a syntax hack) -- I have solved the problem by generating the data in a transposed fashion. I welcome  comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure of the result you want but this gives a line per day:

```
CREATE TABLE #VistitorStat
(
 datelow datetime,
 datehigh datetime,
 name varchar(255),
 cnt  int
)


insert into #VistitorStat
      select  '2009-07-25 00:00:00.000','2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',   'New Visitor',       221 
union select  '2009-07-25 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',   'Unique Visitors',   225
union select  '2009-07-25 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',   'Return Visitors',   0
union select  '2009-07-25 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',   'Repeat Visitors',   22
union select  '2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000',   'New Visitor'    ,   263
union select  '2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000',   'Unique Visitors',   269
union select  '2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000',   'Return Visitors',   4
union select  '2009-07-26 00:00:00.000',' 2009-07-27 00:00:00.000',   'Repeat Visitors',   38


select * from #VistitorStat 
pivot (
    sum(cnt)
    for name in ([New Visitor],[Unique Visitors],[Return Visitors], [Repeat Visitors])

) p
```

Comment: (+1) Yep, that did the trick. The syntax is very odd -- it doesn't make sense even -- I don't want to add the `cnt` values -- yet it works :D.